# Lazy Initialization exception with spring and hibernate when used outside the transactional boundary like JSP File

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am using spring 4.0 and hibernate 4.3,

The problem is that if I get the hibernate session object through session.openSession() then i can initialized the lazy object anywhere including JSP but then i have to manage the session object of hibernate by my own which is wrong practice.

But if i create the session by session.getCurrentSession() then i get the benefit of spring managing the session for me but then this problem occurs that i cant lazy initialised the object out side the transactional boundaries like JSP.

I don't want to explicitly set the query fetch mode to eager or join every time for every lazy object also every time i don't want to change the domain object annotation changed to Eager.

Overall i am just asking that what is the correct way to deal with lazy initialization object when used with spring and hibernate. Please Help

Comment: Hi Shivam, welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the section [ask] and consider in providing a [mcve] for your problem. It will be of much help for us to help you.

Comment: You should never have the methods of calling database functions in a jsp. The best way to use hibernate session for lazy is using as an example below

Answer (score 0):

Below is my logic to get lazy loaded data when needed.

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;




    public class UserDAO implements GenericDao<User,String> {

        @Autowired
        private HibernateTemplate template;

        @Override
        public User load(final String id) {
            return template.load(User.class,id);
        }

        @Override
        public User get(final String id) {
            return template.get(User.class,id);
        }

        public User getUserVideos(final String id) {
            User user = template.get(User.class,id);
            template.initialize(user.getVideo());
            return user;
        }



        @Override
        public Long count() {
            return new Long(template.loadAll(User.class).size());
        }

        @Override
        public void flush() {
            template.flush();
        }

    }
```

And you can use the returned objects in your JSP or whereever you want